# Localizing Github repo?

Tags: regex, github, localization, translation

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, although I'm sure someone might be able to guide me in the right direction. The problem/question I have is about a github repo that is in another language (which I haven't the faintest clue of understanding). Is there a standard way of translating/localizing an entire codebase/repo? I have some ideas of ways that might be (tedious) to do it, but I'm looking for the correct or best way.

Fortunately the code seems to be mostly in english, but all of the comments and output for example are in cyrillic (not sure if it's russian, serbian, etc). Which approach do I need to take to make this as painless as possible? Is `regex` the answer, or is something like a copy/paste (ugh!) using `google translate`? Thanks in advance.

**Code Sample:**

```
if (!defined("FILE")) die("Ошибка доступа.");
$data_filename = "data.txt"; // имя файла с данными сниффера
...
```

**Google Translate:**

```
if (defined ("FILE")) die ("Error Access.");
data_filename $ = "data.txt"; // Filename with data sniffer 
...
```

While far from perfect, it does translate - but screws with the code.

Comment: It's definitely Russian. And Google didn't understand the text properly. It should be "Access error" and "Sniffer data")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea that works for the example you posted (though definitely not for every language in the world):

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    foreignStart = None
    for ii, ch in enumerate(line):
        if foreignStart is None and ord(ch) > 127:
            foreignStart = ii
        elif foreignStart is not None and ord(ch) <= 127 and ch != ' ':
            sys.stdout.write("TRANSLATE(")
            sys.stdout.write(line[foreignStart:ii])
            sys.stdout.write(")")
            foreignStart = None
        if ord(ch) <= 127 and not (foreignStart is not None and ch == ' '):
            sys.stdout.write(ch)
```

This will print:

```
if (!defined("FILE")) die("TRANSLATE(Ошибка доступа).");
$data_filename = "data.txt"; // TRANSLATE(имя файла с данными сниффера)
...
```

I think you can see where you'll need to insert calls to a machine translation API (Google or Yandex...).  You should of course cache results you've already translated in a text file somewhere, which will also allow you to override results you don't like from the API.

Comment: Wow, that's more than I would have ever expected someone to do, very very helpful. thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know I paired your code with some google translate and it works great: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a0cb019cf94e4207bd9d

Comment: Awesome, that was quick.  :)